# How to combine multiple word documents (differently formatted) while keeping the same format?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to combine separately written chapters to one **MsWord** document. Then later add Table of content after the introduction.

How can I merge these multiple word documents (differently formatted) while keeping their format?

for e.g. Intro/Cover has **roman page numbering** and chapters have **hindu-arabic page numbering**. All the chapters have unique formatting (i.e. headers).

**** Each chapter had an **EndNote** bibliography.

If I copy-paste all to one documents, I have to format everything again manually :(

I am using **MsWord 2016**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4DAe.png